# Find assigned EventHandlers in debug in asp.net / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having an issue with asp.net and a third party control that is embedded in a user control.  I want to assign an event handler to one of the third party control's events.  It allows the assignment but the event handler never get's touched.  I believe that I am either messing up the event handler assignment or assigning it at the wrong time.  I want to track the assignment of the event handler through debug.  How can I inspect which event handlers are assigned to a control in debug?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the source for the user control, you can add some logging code to the [add/remove accessors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163533.aspx) for the event.

In VS debugger, you can also check the contents of the `_invocationList` field in the event (base MulticastDelegate class). Expanding it will show you a list of attached handlers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the source.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Watch (or Locals or Autos) window in Visual Studio, you can dig into the delegate holding the event (assuming it's a standard event) and see which method(s) it contains.

### EDIT:

If the event only has one handler, you will see it in `base.base.Method` on the delegate field.  If it has multiple handlers, `base._invocationList` will be an array of single-method delegates; you can check `base.base.Method` in each one.

If the `_invocationList` of a delegate isn't null, it's `base.base.Method` will be ignored.